# JRI R integration from java, some statements don't work?

Tags: java, r, jri

If I create a data frame in R, I can drop one of the columns like this:

```
testset[,-7]  # drops the 7th column
```

Whilst I can create a data frame with JRI, I cannot perform the same operation from Java:

```
REXP df = REXPGenericVector(new RList(new REXP[] { ... })); //details left out
// REngine previously contructed
engine.assign("testset",df); // works
engine.parseAndEval("testset"); // works, returns an REXP with the data frame I just created
engine.parseAndEval("testset[,-7]"); // broken, returns org.rosuda.REngine.REXPNull
```

Similarly, if I replicate code I have in R with simple parse/eval statements they seem to fall over on certain statements. Below is an example of a support vector machine training/prediction

```
engine.parseAndEval("svm.model <- svm(Class ~ ., data = trainset, cost = 100, gamma = 1)");
engine.parseAndEval("svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testset_noclass)"); // testset_noclass same as testset, except without a column
REXP r = engine.parseAndEval("svm.pred"); // r is a  org.rosuda.REngine.REXPNull
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at the documentation of class Rengine, http://www.rosuda.org/r/nightly/javadoc/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html , doesn't seem to show the method "parseAndEval", only "eval". Notice that there are two R engine's, (2 abstractions), one that is part of JRI (which seems to be what you are using) and another, which is part of org.rosuda.REngine (this one does contain the method "parseAndEval").

Comment: There are two classes Rengine and REngine, which is a wrapper for the former. The REngine class has the method.